# How we can get videos thumbnail stored on dropbox

Tags: php, video, dropbox

i am using `GetThumbnail` method of the php sdk. Does this return videos thumbnails also?

I am calling it like

```
$dropbox->GetThumbnail($files[0]->path,'s','jpeg',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can apparently only get a preview for image files smaller than 20MB, according to the [Dropbox Core API Documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#thumbnails).

Dropbox Core API is the underlying interface for all official Dropbox mobile apps and Dropbox's SDKs.